# Is logging in Tomcat webserver async by default?

Tags: java, tomcat, slf4j

Usually my logging is as follows:

`private final Logger LOGGER = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());`

Question: if I deploy my app as a `war` to a `tomcat` webserver, is the logging sync or async by default?

I'm asking because the tomcats `logging.properties` file defines the `AsyncFileHandler` throughout, like `.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler`.

My question is, if all of my log statements are "passed" to that tomcat async file handler, and then logged async automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat's logging is irrelevant if you are using a separate logging framework (such as SLF4J) in your web application. The SLF4J docs should tell you what is synchronous and what is asynchronous in that framework.

For the record, Tomcat's internal logging is synchronous until it gets to the `AsyncFileHandler` where it is buffered and written asynchronously on a separate thread (because writing to the file system is usually the slowest part of the logging call).